# Adding a prefix to header row in csv file with awk

Tags: csv, awk, header

I am currently working with datasets collected in large CSV files (over 1600 columns and 100 rows). Excel or LibreOffice calc can't easily handle these files for concatenating a prefix or suffix to the header row, which is what I would have done on a smaller dataset.
Researching the topic I was able to come up with the following command:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } {if(NR==1){print "prefix_"$0}; if(NR>1){print; next}}' input.csv >output.csv
```

Unfortunately, this only adds the prefix to the first cell. For example:

**Input:**

```
head_1,head_2,head_3,[...],head_n

"value_1","value_2","value_3",[...],"value_n"
```

**Expected Output:**

```
prefix_head_1,prefix_head_2,prefix_head_3,[...],prefix_head_n

"value_1","value_2","value_3",[...],"value_n"
```

**Real Output:**

```
prefix_head_1,head_2,head_3,[...],head_n

"value_1","value_2","value_3",[...],"value_n"
```

As the column number may be variable across different csv files, I would like a solution that doesn't require enumeration of all columns as found elsewhere.
This is necessary as the following step is to combine various (5 or 6) large csv files in a single csv database by combining all columns (the rows refer to the same instances, in the same order, across all files).
Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i="prefix_"$i} 1' file
```